# Can I install pysptk with Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run a function that uses pysptk in combination with Librosa to calculate MFCC values from sound files. I am trying to run the function from a Jupyter notebook within the Anaconda Navigator, which means I have to use either the CMD.exe Prompt or Powershell Prompt as my terminal. I've tried installing once with conda using the command `conda install pysptk` which gives me this message:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pysptk

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I then tried installing with pip using `pip install pypstk` which gives me this error message:

```
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysptk
Failed to build pysptk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysptk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Is there a way I can install pysptk in the Anaconda environment?